# Technical meaning of C# ref

Tags: c#, pointers, ref

I understand that c# ref allows you to send a pointer to an object. I'm just wondering what this means for what is actually being sent to a function under the hood.

As far as I understand it is like:

DoSomething (ref exampleObject)
--> here a pointer to exampleObject is sent to the function

DoSomething (exampleObject)
--> here an array of pointers to the object's properties is sent to the function.

Is this correct? And will the second function also create a pointer for value types? (Seeing as they are properties and their value has to be saved on the heap in order to retain the  referential integrity of the object)

A bit clearer explanation:
*Object A is in memory location 5
*It has the properties object B and object C

Now I call DoSomething (A)
--> as objects are handled via pointers by default I pass a pointer value of 5, so that I may manipulate the value at memory adress 5. How does C# know at which memory adress the properties of the sent object are located?

Now I call DoSomething (ref A)
--> At this point I create a new pointer (let's say 6) which points to the other pointer. So now I pass in 6, which allows me to change the value of memory adress 6, which conveniently turns out to be 5, the location of object A. So now I can change the memory to which the A object passed in is pointing to.

The thing I do not understand is how the properties are found in memory? Somewhere an array of pointers or a pointer to an array of pointers has to be send, right?

Comment: "I understand that c# ref allows you to send a pointer to an object." - that's not what  it means... when you assign `var obj = GetSomeObject();` - *that* is assigning a reference (which is *essentially* fancy-talk for a pointer) to an object

Comment: exampleObject is already a pointer.  It points to the object stored on the heap.  So `ref` gets you a pointer to a pointer.  The kind of detail that used to empty half the Programming 101 class before the end of the semester.  There is no "array of pointers", the pointer stored in exampleObject is sufficient to locate the members.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I get that, but if there is no array of pointers, how can one refer to all the properties of the object? One needs to know their memory locations in order to change their values, right?

Comment: Properties are code, not data.  The CLR knows where the code is stored, the just-in-time compiler generated that code and knows how to generate the CALL instruction.  Fields are data, the exampleObject pointer points to them.  The just-in-time compiler knows the offset of the field value within the object.  First field has an offset of 0, second field has a higher offset, depending on the type of the first field.

Comment: @Hans Passant: ah so you are saying the fields are stored in order in memory so they can be accessed via pointer arithmetic behind the scene?

Comment: Right, the processor has a dedicated addressing mode to make that as fast as possible.

Comment: @HansPassant: And does a ref-to-ref give you a pointer-to-pointer? And a ref-to-ref-to-ref gives you a pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer?

Comment: Theoretically, no syntax for that beyond the `&` operator.

Comment: @HansPassant: WAT? Sure there is. Remember what you wrote up there? Calling `DoSomething (ref exampleObject)` takes a pointer to `exampleObject` and since `exampleObject` is a of a reference type "`ref` gets you a pointer to a pointer." That's a direct quote. So does that mean that inside the function (e.g. `static void DoSomething(ref Klass obj) { foo(obj); }`) `obj` is a pointer to a pointer? Remember that that's what you said `ref` gets, so that's what's passed to the function. And what if `DoSomething` passes `ref obj` to another function? Is that a pointer to a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: `ref` of a `ref` of a `ref` twelve times deep! http://ideone.com/B00hYe Man, how many pointers deep we've gone there...

Comment: @conio you are wrong. there is no `ref` to `ref` in C#, nor can you imitate it by doing recusive `ref` . all the recursive functions you showed have the same `ref` that gets passed by value. if you pass `ref Foo` to a function which gets `ref Foo foo` as parameters, you always gets the same `ref`

Comment: @conio just like `(int** i)` in C++ will not make a pointer-to pointer to pointer to pointer(...) if you recursively pass `int**` to the same function, it will just copy the `int**`

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding in the second case

```
 DoSomething(exampleObject)
```

the address of `exampleObject` is given as an argument to the method `DoSomething`, which means that in `DoSomething` the object's properties can be reassigned (supposing a reference type is used), but assignmet of `exampleObject` does not change it in the scope of the caller, as the address of `exampleObject` is modified on the stack, not in the scope of the caller. On the other hand, in the first case

```
DoSomething(ref exampleObject)
```

a pointer to the address of `exampleObject` is given as an argument to `DoSomething`, which consequently means that besides changing the properties of `exampleObject`, the reference to `exampleObject` itself can be reassigned. Consequently,`exampleObject` can be exchanged, an effect which is also visible within the scope of the caller.

Comment: If an adress of the object is sent (like you said about the function without ref), I should be able to change the value of the object, right? (Since you can change the value of the memory adress a pointer points to) But I cannot, I can only change its properties. This means that only the addresses of the properties are available to the called function.  This is why I presume C# sends an array of pointers (more specifically a pointer to an array of pointers) under the hood when sending an object. So what is being sent exactly?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you came in c# from c++ you can imagine ref as reference in c++ like that:

```
void foo(A*& a)
{ 
     // Here you can change object's state
     // Also you can change value of pointer
     // Caller will have new value of pointer
}
void foo(A* a)
{
    // Here you can change object's state
    // Also you can change value of copy of pointer
    // Caller will have old value of pointer
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `DoSomething(ref exampleObject)` if we know or expect that `DoSomething` may perform the act of "calculating a value or creating a new object and returning it to us". And that we know if the declaration of `DoSomething` also contains the `ref` keyword.

If before the call your `exampleObject` contains a certain value, or it is pointing to a certain object (or even null), then after the call it *may* contain a new value, or it *may* be pointing to a new object or it *may* have been changed to null.

There is no **certainty** or **obligation** for this to happen with `ref`, just that *if* `DoSomething` decides that `exampleObject` should change, *then* we will get that new value or object (or null). And otherwise we keep what we had before.

This is true for both value types (numbers, bools, structs) and reference types (objects), that is why I kept saying "a new value or a new object or null".

***Edit:***
I deliberately avoided to mention *pointers*. Unless you are doing low level stuff, in C#/.NET you almost never have to know about pointers. It usually suffices to understand the concepts and the rules that govern them.

Answer (score 0):

I always compare pointers to voodoo dolls - whatever you do to the voodoo doll, will affect the person the voodoo doll "points" to.

so C# reference is like a voodoo doll - it attaches to an object, and you can affect the object by consuming the voodoo doll.

but what happens if I suddenly want the voodoo doll to point to different person than it pointed before? using the voodoo doll affects the person it points to - not the voodoo doll itself.

what is the solution? creating another voodoo doll - to the original voodoo doll! this way I can mess with the original doll and not only with the person it points to.

so `ref` in C# is a reference to a reference - it allows you to modify a reference, and not only the object it points to.

behind the scenes, a reference is just number which indicates where the object sits on the RAM. a `ref` reference is yet another number, but which indicates where is the original reference sits on the RAM, and not where does the object it points at sits.

Comment: Why do you think that a voodoo doll that points to a voodoo doll can't mess with the person the second voodoo doll points too? And if you think that every `ref` is a pointer ("just number which indicates where the object sits on the RAM") **to the original object reference** rather than to the object itself, same question as to Hans Passant - what about a ref to a ref to a ref?

Comment: @conio I agree that a better phrase would be "not only with", fixed

Answer (score 0):

No, *this* is not correct.

What `ref` brings to the table is reference semantics.

When you call a function `foo(T arg)` - **regardless of whether T is a value type or a reference type** (I can't stress that enough) - `foo` gets a copy of T.

The difference between value types and reference types is that **names** of value types refer to the interesting stuff, while **names** of reference types refer to references (or pointers) to the interesting stuff. It follows that when you copy an object of a value type you get a copy of the interesting stuff and when you copy of said reference to the interesting stuff.

Some image I found on Google instead of drawing one on my own:

[image]

The copies in the image are basically what happens when you call the `foo(T arg`) is was talking about. In both cases we `arg` contains a copy of what was passed to `foo`. If `T` is `int` it's the number you're interested in. If `T` is `Circle` then `arg` is the "address"<sup>1</sup> that the argument passed to `foo` contained. Instead of talking about pointers or references we can talk about arrows. variables of reference types contain arrows to the interesting stuff, while variables of value types contain the stuff itself.

This is demonstrated by the following code:

```cs
using System;
class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    Foo foo1 = new Foo();
    foo1.i = 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Main(): foo1.i: {0}", foo1.i);

    doStuffToFoo(foo1, 5);
    Console.WriteLine("Main(): foo1.i: {0}", foo1.i);

    Console.WriteLine();

    Bar bar1;
    bar1.j = 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Main(): bar1.j: {0}", bar1.j);

    doStuffToBar(bar1, 5);
    Console.WriteLine("Main(): bar1.j: {0}", bar1.j);
  }

  static void doStuffToFoo(Foo aFoo, int aInt) {
    aFoo.i = aInt;
    aFoo = new Foo();
    aFoo.i = 123;
    Console.WriteLine("doStuffToFoo: aFoo.i: {0}", aFoo.i);
  }

  static void doStuffToBar(Bar aBar, int aInt) {
    aBar.j = aInt;
    aBar = new Bar();
    aBar.j = 123;
    Console.WriteLine("doStuffToBar: aBar.j: {0}", aBar.j);
  }
}

class Foo {
  public int i;
}

struct Bar {
  public int j;
}
```

See if you understand what it prints before trying or reading on.

The variable `aFoo` inside `doStuffToFoo` is a **copy** of `foo1`. Plain and simple. `aFoo` and `foo1` are distinct variables (stored in distinct locations on the stack - `foo1` in `Main`'s stack frame and `aFoo` in `doStuffToFoo`'s stack frame - assuming there is a stack, since [the stack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) [is an implementation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two/) [detail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/09/30/the-truth-about-value-types/)), and they both contain arrows to the same `Foo` object.

When you refer to fields of both these variables they access the same `Foo` object through their respective arrows. But when you assign a `new Foo()` to `aFoo` it only changes the arrow in `aFoo` to point to the new `Foo` object. It does nothing to the other arrow to the first `Foo` object, stored safely inside the `foo1` variable and inaccessible to the code in `doStuffToFoo`. That's why you don't see "123" back in `Main`.

And all that brings us to `ref`. `ref T v` says that `v` is not a new variable of type T (that contains some interesting stuff if `T` is a value type or an arrow to some interesting stuff if `T` is a reference type). Rather `v` is an **alias** to whatever gets passed as argument. It is a second **name** to some other variable.

If you add the following code to the example above you'll see that in effect.

```cs
/***** inside Main: *****/
Foo foo2 = new Foo();
Foo foo3 = foo2;
foo2.i = 1;
Console.WriteLine("Main(): foo2.i: {0}", foo2.i);
Console.WriteLine("Main(): foo3.i: {0}", foo3.i);

doStuffToFooRef(ref foo2, 5);
Console.WriteLine("Main(): foo2.i: {0}", foo2.i);
Console.WriteLine("Main(): foo3.i: {0}", foo3.i);
/***** until here *****/

static void doStuffToFooRef(ref Foo aFoo, int aInt) {
  aFoo.i = aInt;
  aFoo = new Foo();
  aFoo.i = 123;
  Console.WriteLine("doStuffToFooRef: aFoo.i: {0}", aFoo.i);
}
```

Now `aFoo` is a another name to `foo2`. When you assign to "`aFoo`" you assign to "`foo2`", because both these names refer to the same variable (storage location). That's what happens during the assignment in `doStuffToFooRef`:

[image]

(`i` is still zero since it's before we put there 123.)

Try it here: https://repl.it/E80a

C# `ref` is like C++ references in this respect, as Александр Лысенко wrote in his answer. While technically, a `ref SomeReferenceType x` **may be** "pointer to pointer" as some have said, this doesn't catch the real meaning of `ref`, and dwells on an implementation detail that needn't be always true (it might be optimized out). It implies that adding `ref` adds a pointer. So is a ref-of-a-ref of a reference type is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer? Does each additional `ref` adds a level of indirection?

---

<sup>1</sup> For the purposes of this discussion we don't care if it's really an address or something else. Since objects may be moved in memory, we understand that it's probably not a virtual memory address of the host machine/operating system, but it is an address in the broad sense.
Some make a distinction between references and pointers, the latter are numerical memory addresses, but others aren't afraid to call these things pointers too, because they point to objects. For example, the Java Language Specification ([§4.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)) explicitly says:

> The reference values (often just *references*) are pointers to these objects, and a special null reference, which refers to no object.

They emphasize "references" - the new term they introduce - but what pointers are is obvious to the reader in their opinion, and there too objects are not unmovable AFAIK.